# WordPress Active Directory integration

Tags: single-sign-on

I have an Internal WordPress site and would like for the Active Directory users to Automatically authenticate to the site using the Windows Credentials. What would be the best way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated setup. I would recommend using https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress.